# Issue with 0 byte files in node_modules in docker container built with pnpm

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, express, pnpm

**The Issue**

I have a Typescript pnpm monorepo that is working nicely in local development. It's ready to deploy and I am trying to Dockerize the server for deployment. I'm running into an issue where the image will be created successfully, the node_modules folder looks correct with all dependencies listed, however every file in that folder is a 0 byte file, and the Docker container will exit with the message:

```bash
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'express' imported from /prod/server/src/main.js
  at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
  at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:794:9)
  at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:843:20)
  at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1058:11)
  at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/hooks:654:28)
  at Hooks.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/hooks:309:30)
  at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:312:26)
  at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:172:38)
  at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:40)
  at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

I suspect my issue may have something to do with the `pnpm deploy` command, since I can build and run the server fine locally by manually entering the commands in the same order (ie, `install` > `build` > `node dist/main.js`), but I haven't been able to figure it out for sure.

[image: File structure of built Docker container with node_modules all 0 bytes]

**Some relevant files**

Because this is a monorepo, I'm using the guide on the pnpm recipes page for [how to Dockerize a monorepo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7a5C.png).

```
# Dockerfile
FROM node:19-slim AS base
ARG service
ENV PNPM_HOME="/pnpm"
ENV PATH="$PNPM_HOME:$PATH"
RUN corepack enable
COPY . /usr/application

FROM base AS deps
ARG service
WORKDIR /usr/application/${service}
RUN --mount=type=cache,id=pnpm,target=/pnpm/store pnpm install --prod --frozen-lockfile

FROM base as build
ARG service
WORKDIR /usr/application/${service}
RUN --mount=type=cache,id=pnpm,target=/pnpm/store pnpm install --frozen-lockfile
RUN pnpm prisma generate
RUN pnpm run build
RUN pnpm deploy --filter=${service} --prod /prod/${service}

FROM base as server
COPY --from=deps /usr/application/${service}/node_modules /prod/${service}/node_modules
COPY --from=build /prod/${service}/dist /prod/${service}
COPY --from=build /prod/${service}/package.json /prod/${service}
WORKDIR /prod/${service}
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "pnpm", "run", "start:prod" ]
```

I'm building this image with the following command:
`docker build -t mono-image . --file Dockerfile --build-arg="service=server"`

This image builds fine, but it's only when I try to run the container from the Docker Desktop dashboard that I see the error posted above.

My pnpm-workspace.yaml. `app` is the frontend client, the rest is self-explanatory I think:

```yaml
packages:
  - server
  - app
  - shared
```

My `package.json` in the server workspace:

```json
//package.json 

{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 19 < 20"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/tsc -p ./tsconfig.json",
    "start": "tsx src/main.ts",
    "start:dev": "tsx watch src/main.ts",
    "start:prod": "node src/main.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/connect-pg-simple": "^7.0.1",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.14",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.18",
    "@types/express-session": "^1.17.8",
    "@types/node": "^18.17.4",
    "@types/passport": "^1.0.13",
    "prisma": "^5.3.1",
    "typescript": "^5.3.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "connect-pg-simple": "^9.0.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "iso-3166-2": "^1.0.0",
    "node-fetch": "^3.3.2",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-magic-link": "^2.1.0",
    "passport-magic-login": "^1.2.2",
    "pg": "^8.11.3",
    "postmark": "3.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "shared": "workspace:^",
    "simple-xml-to-json": "^1.1.7",
    "socket.io": "^4.7.2",
    "tslib": "~2.6",
    "tsx": "^3.12.10"
  }
}
```

My package.json at the project root:

```json
{
  "name": "pnpm-monorepo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "pnpm --stream -r start",
    "start:dev": "pnpm --stream -r run start:dev"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "app": "workspace:*",
    "server": "workspace:*"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^5.3.1",
    "prisma": "^5.3.1",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2"
  }
}
```

I am using Typescript, so I also have a tsconfig that builds into a a dist folder at the top level in my server workspace. Even though it's building fine, I am happy to get tips on how to improve this for a 2023 Express server. Here's that `tsconfig.json`:

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "Node16",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true, // added for error related to "export module = "

    /* Bundler mode */
    // "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    // "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node16",
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmitOnError": false,

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src", "config.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "test", "dist", "**/*spec.ts"]
  // "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

Hope I've supplied enough info to help troubleshoot, but can provide any other info if it would be helpful. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: that's some advance multi-stage dockering :D
I would start the investigation by dropping all the mounting though. Copying stuff between layers is fine. Copying dependencies from your host is not. Depending on the dependency, it might require running some post-install scripts that will further configure it (or build it with node-gyp) specifically for the environment you're installing it on. 
But yeah... I guess I'm not as advanced with my dockering as you are as I have never used the --mount flag... but yeah... that looks the most sus to me

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, it is indeed a lot! I suppose it could be made simpler but Docker is really not my strength :) The mount flag is for pnpm, and comes straight from their "recipe" for [how to work with Docker](https://pnpm.io/docker), which has 4 stages. You're probably onto something though. I have tried to reduce the complexity by not `pnpm install`-ing at the monorepo level and just at the project level but it yielded similar results. I'll just try the build step and cut out the `deploy` command and work from there. Cheers

Comment: I Should correct my previous comment– the mount flag is not for pnpm commands. See docs for RUN [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run---mounttypecache)